# Swift trouble loading xml. Where's the content?

Tags: swift

I'm having a pinch of trouble loading xml to tvOS via swift. After looking through some examples here is what I've come up with for a test:

## AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

let xmlUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://investorwired.com/analysis/feed")!


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: xmlUrl)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")})

        task.resume();


        return true
    }
}
```

## output

```
Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7faa02b00e90> { URL: http://investorwired.com/analysis/feed } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 04 Nov 2015 18:02:39 GMT";
    Etag = "\"6a9e5b9fbb11708878ca4559494b2b13\"";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.0";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,Cookie";
    "WP-Super-Cache" = "Served legacy cache file";
    "X-Pingback" = "http://investorwired.com/xmlrpc.php";
} })
```

Which is only the headers of the transaction. How do I get the actual XML response?

**FYI**, for this test I've had to allow arbitrary loads in my plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

## other

- xcode 7.1
- tvOS 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the `response` parameter, it's in the `data` parameter.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let xmlUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://investorwired.com/analysis/feed")!

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: xmlUrl)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")

            if let someData = data, dataString = NSString(data: someData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                print(dataString)
            }
            else {
                print("Invalid or no data received")
            }
        })

        task.resume();


        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been scouring the web for hours with no avail.

Comment: @Jackson Sure.  It's worth noting that if you don't use a data task, then you'll have to implement some of the NSURLSessionDataDelegate and/or NSURLSessionDelegate methods to collect the data.